# append value to slice of a slice

Tags: arrays, go, append

consider this piece of code:

```
func main() {
    items := func1()

    for _, v := range items {
        v.Status = append(v.Status, false)
    }

    fmt.Println(items)

}

//TestCaseItem represents the test case
type TestCaseItem struct {
    Actual   []string
    Expected []string
    Status   []bool
}

func func1() []TestCaseItem {
    var tc = make([]TestCaseItem, 0)

    var item = &TestCaseItem{}
    item.Actual = append(item.Actual, "test1")
    item.Actual = append(item.Actual, "test2")

    tc = append(tc, *item)

    return tc
}
```

i have an slice of type `TestCaseItem` struct. In that struct i have slice of string and bool properties. first i call `func1` function to grab some data and then iterate over that slice and try to append more data insdide, but the output of this code is `[{[test1 test2] [] []}]` where are the booleans ?

i feel like the  problem is  `[]TestCaseItem` cuz its a slice that holds values rather than pointers and maybe i'll miss sth. can anybody explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're appending the bool values to copies of your TestCaseItems.

You either need to use a pointer to the items:

```
func func1() []*TestCaseItem {
    var tc = make([]*TestCaseItem, 0)

    var item = &TestCaseItem{}
    item.Actual = append(item.Actual, "test1")
    item.Actual = append(item.Actual, "test2")

    tc = append(tc, item)

    return tc
}
```

Or you need to append to the `Status` field of the `TestCaseItem` value that's in the slice.

```
for i := range items {
    items[i].Status = append(items[i].Status, false)
}
```

Comment: yes thats true but all of them are slices so as far as i know slices are references to an underlying array, but in this case they are not referencing why is that?

Comment: @kyur: It doesn't have anything to do with the pointer in the slice itself, you were copying the `TestCaseItem` values, which means you weren't writing to the same slice values.